# Problems with static and non static

Tags: java, static

I have some problems with non-static variables referenced from a static context and i don't know, how to change my methods to solve it.

The first one is this one, which is supposed to spawn a bullet at the position the shooter has at the moment of firing:

```
World.addObject(new bulletH(), (int)posX , (int)posY);
```

Also the trigger for removing bullets, when they leave the world doesn't work:

```
if(posX<0 || posX> getWorld().getWidth() || posY <0 || posY > getWorld().getHeight()){
        World.removeObject(this);
```

I would really appreciate it, if you could help me with these to problems and make me understand, how i can circumvent this error.

//edit

class Hero

```
    import greenfoot.*; 
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Hero extends alive
{
    private double mspeed = 100.0;
    private long frameBegin = 0;
    private double posX;
    private double posY;
    private boolean isJumping = false;
    private double maxJumpTime = 0.35;
    private double jumpTime = 0;
    private double jspeed = 250.0;
    private double fspeed = jspeed;
    private boolean faceR;
    private int hoch = 30;
    private int breit = 26;
    private boolean onCD = false;
    private long CD = 0;

    public Hero() {
    }

    public void addedToWorld(World world) {
        posX = getX();
        posY = getY();
        faceR = true;
    }

    public static void schuss(){
        /*World.addObject(new bulletH(), (int)posX , (int)posY);
        if(faceR=true){
          bullet.firedR=true;
        }
        else{
          bullet.firedR=false;  
        }

        */
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new  Rectangle((int)posX, (int)posY, breit,hoch);      
    }

    public void act(){
        double deltaTime;
            if(frameBegin == 0) {
            deltaTime = 0;
        }
            else{
            deltaTime = ((double) (System.currentTimeMillis()-frameBegin))/1000;
        }
        frameBegin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("A")){
               posX -= mspeed * deltaTime;
               faceR = false;
            }

        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("D")){
                posX += mspeed * deltaTime;
                faceR = true;
            }

        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("W") && !getIntersectingObjects(Floor.class).isEmpty()) {
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTime = 0;
        }

        if((!Greenfoot.isKeyDown("W") || (jumpTime > maxJumpTime)) && isJumping) {
            isJumping = false;
        }

        if(isJumping) {
            posY -= jspeed * deltaTime;
            jumpTime += deltaTime;
        }  

        if(getIntersectingObjects(Floor.class).isEmpty() && !isJumping) {
            posY += fspeed *deltaTime;
        }

        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("Space")) {
            if(onCD = false){
                schuss();
                onCD = true;
            }
        }
        if(posY > getWorld().getHeight()){
         Greenfoot.setWorld(new gameover());   
        }

        setLocation((int)posX, (int)posY);
        CD += deltaTime;

        if(CD> 0.3){
            CD=0;
            onCD = false;
        }
    }   
}
```

class bullet

```
import greenfoot.*; 
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class bullet extends Actor
{
    public int mspeed = 250;
    public boolean firedR = true;
    public long frameBegin = 0;
    public int yspeed = 0;
    public int posX;
    public int posY;
    private int hoch = getImage().getHeight();
    private int breit = getImage().getWidth();

    public void addedToWorld(World world) {
        posX = getX();
        posY = getY();
    }

        public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new  Rectangle((int)posX, (int)posY, breit,hoch);
    }

    public void move(){
        double deltaTime;
        if(frameBegin == 0) {
            deltaTime = 0;
        }
        else{
            deltaTime = ((double) (System.currentTimeMillis()-frameBegin))/1000;
        }
        frameBegin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(firedR=true){
            posX += mspeed * deltaTime;
        }

        else{
            posX -= mspeed * deltaTime;
        }

        posY+= yspeed * deltaTime;


        setLocation((int)posX, (int)posY);
    }   

    public void act(){

    }

}
```

Comment: It might help if you showed us which variables are static and which are non-static, and exactly what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Which variables are **static** and which variables are **non-static** ?

Comment: the posX/posY are non-static, rest should be static.

Answer (score 1):

There is a critical error here. You cannot reference non static variables from static context **unless** you instanciate your class.
By definition, static variables/methods are also called Class Variables/Methods, which means you don't need to have an instance of that class for it to be accessible.
Non static variables/methods are also called Instance variables/methods, which means you **must** have an instance of that class, and you may only have access to these through your object.

That said, if you must have access to said variables, either you make them static, or you move your code to non static scope.
You may access those variables if you create an instance of your object, but I don't think that would serve your purpose.

Comment: well, I reckon your static method is `schuss`. You could make that method non static. After all, if someone's shooting, that is one instance of your class hero that is shooting, and not your class Hero. Just like if a man is shooting, it would be Jack, not Class Man